# Will a Fixed String * 7 use less memory than an Integer of =Len(7)?

Tags: string, excel, types, integer, vba

Will a Fixed String use less memory than an Integer?

```
Public Type MyType

UserID As Integer 'All My User IDs are less than 7 integers in length
UserID As String * 7 ''Will a Fixed String use less memory than an Integer?

End Type
```

Is there a way to test in a VBA Procedure?

Comment: the maximum number that can be stored in Integer is 32,767 (2 bytes) and in Long 2,147,483,647 (4 bytes) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary

Answer (score 1):

The string will use more memory

Integer (should be Long according to example) is 4 bytes, string at least 8.

-- edit according to comment

Comment: in VBA Integer is 2 bytes and Long is 4 bytes

Comment: Then the example is wrong since 2 bytes will not hold all integers of 6 digits, i.e. 999999. 

My answer was based on the actual description not the error in the example.

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same. I just noticed in the linked documentation that the storage size of variable-length String is "10 bytes + string length" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary, but doesn't seem accurate because strings use 2 bytes per character

Comment: @Slai Do all strings now use 2 bytes per character?  I thought is was just the Unicode characters that do that.  Hence `Chr` vs `ChrW`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I can't find good reference, but VBA uses Unicode encoding for all strings (and the VBA editor uses ANSI encoding) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261360. You can also check the bytes per character with LENB() or converting to byte array https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-6-faster-strings-and-byte-arrays/

Comment: @Slai Thanks for those references! Very useful. I note that `StrConv` with the `fromUnicode` argument will convert the string into a *single-byte per letter* variable.  I wonder if VBA has always used two bytes per letter.

Answer (score 1):

`lenB(var)` will give an idea of its size.

```
Private Type MyType
    UserID  As Integer
    sUserID As String * 7
End Type

Dim x As MyType
    x.UserID = 123
    x.sUserID = "123"

Debug.Print LenB(yourType.UserID)     
Debug.Print LenB(yourType.sUserID)
Debug.Print LenB(yourType)

2 
14 
16
```

For the string is a little more complex, its not just a series of bytes in memory rather its stored as as a BSTR which has a 6 byte overhead (4 for length, 2 per character and a \0\0 terminator).

**BUT** You should pick the *correct type for the data you want to store* rather than worrying about the difference - in your example its 12 bytes which is utterly irrelevant in this day and age.